# How can I make intellij "shorten" folders that have no files in between them?

Tags: intellij-idea

For example, if a path goes io/github/temp/abc and there are no files in each folder, simply the next folder, how can I compress them so they don't take up a huge part of my screen as they nest towards the right?

Attached image shows some example folders; these have no files in between but take up space on the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution to doing something like this is simple. click on the gear settings icon in the top left of the tree; it looks like this
[image]

Then, navigate to "Tree Appearance"

Toggle "Compact Middle Packages"

Enjoy your new organized workspace!